# Change part of sting method and append it to print function

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, centering

I am making part of a python module in python 3 and want it to be able to center text. Here is the code I have:

```
import shutil

width = shutil.get_terminal_size().columns
```

I then want the user to be able to add `.center(width, ' ')` to the end of the string in as simple was as possible.

What is the best way to do this?

Note: The user needs to able to use the method by importing it.

Comment: Welcome to SO! You'll need to include a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Any particular reason why you're trying to center text in a shell?

Comment: @rdas Just for a module to make string styling easy, got colours and bold and underline done, thought i'd add a way to center text

Comment: @technogeek1995 I'm not sure how to do that with this because I don't know how to  make it work

Comment: Do either of these libraries do what you want? [color](https://github.com/timofurrer/colorful) or [clint](https://pypi.org/project/clint/)

Comment: @technogeek1995 they do, but I'm reinventing the wheel for the sake of learning and this is another thing I want to learn

Comment: I would checkout their [source code](https://github.com/timofurrer/colorful/tree/master/examples). You might be able to learn how they do it. I'm not python expert - just trying to help.

Comment: @technogeek1995 Ill have a look thx

Answer (score 1):

I have solved the issue with this:

```
import shutil

width = shutil.get_terminal_size().columns


def center(text):
    return(' ' * int((width/2)-(len(text))/2) + text)
```

Still open to suggestions if there is any ideas